# Logstash: Use JSON filter field as variable in index name

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

With input being a JSON string `{"endpoint": "abc", ... }` I need to forward log entry to index "abc" based on endpoint value;

I would have expected this to work, but it doesn't:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5043" 
    }
}
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"   
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "%{endpoint}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error message?

Comment: Setup a stdout{} output section and make sure that your fields are being created as you expect and at the location you expect them.